# fancybox jquery plugin problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

i am using FancyBox jquery plugin.

i want to display a popup a description window when clicking on a link.the description is getting from a url (something like ajax).but when i click the link fancybox doesn't work and my browser window goes to that url instead of poping up.

why is it so?

my link elements are loading via ajax.

here's my code:

```
$("[id^=pane]").delegate("a.group:not(.haspopup)","click",function() {
    $(this).addClass("haspopup").fancybox({
         'transitionIn'        :       'elastic',
         'transitionOut'       :       'elastic',
         'speedIn'             :       600, 
         'speedOut'            :       200, 
         'overlayShow' :       false
    }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send [ajax request using jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and than use loaded by ajax content for fancybox.

Code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    cache   : false,
    url     : "/data/login.php",
    data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data);
    }
});
```

Also check above example on [fancybox site](http://fancybox.net/blog#login_form)

Comment: thank you.but the '<a>' elements which fancybox should added for them  are also loaded by ajax,not only their content on click.how can i attach fancybox to upcomming elements?